# Is there a simpler way of to write this java program?

Tags: java

This program separates words in a sentence. Please do not use the "split" method as it is outside the curriculum of our school. Please reply without being mean.

```
    int length=0;
    int x=sent.length();
    int a;
    int b=0;
    for(a=0;a<x;a++)
    {
        char z=sent.charAt(a);
        if(z==' ')
        {
            String hell=sent.substring(b,a);
            System.out.println(hell);
            b=b+hell.length()+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are we to know which methods you can use and which you can't. You could write `b = a + 1;`

Comment: what is _sent_? A string?

Comment: What is `length` used for?

Comment: Check out the [StringTokenizer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: this is a very unclear question

Comment: @DrewBuckley It's off the curriculum, he says

Comment: You seem to have problems with this website. Please look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to learn how to ask better questions. (The trick is to think a little on your own first, and _then_ ask a question for a _specific_ problem.)

Comment: @Nabin No, he only said String.split() couldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using indexOf and substrings:

```
int index= word.indexOf(" ");
do{
  System.out.println(word.substring(0, index));
  word = word.substring(index + 1);
  index = word.indexOf(" ");
} while (index != -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use a `java.util.Scanner`.  If this is outside the scope of your school, find a new school!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "Hello world of overflowing   stacks";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(sentence);
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Hello
world
of
overflowing
stacks
```

Comment: java.util.Scanner is in our scope, but they can ask us to specifically use buffered reader, and not use the scanner class, while doing such a question. Indian schools, bro :P

Comment: I don't see a thing wrong with the restrictions. You should learn how a `Scanner` would be implemented before you start taking it for granted. If all the school teaches you is how to use a bunch of canned pieces of code (which is what the standard library is), it is not exactly teaching you right.

Comment: Fair enough point, although the opposite problem (that I have also seen from beginning programmers) is that they try to write everything, and have no idea how to use libraries (including the standard libraries) effectively.  It's a balancing game, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this is

```
for(char ch : sent.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == ' ') ch = '\n';
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Comment: Would this work on a phrase with multiple spaces?  (I like the simplicity of this though!)

Comment: @mattingly890 it would do the same thing i.e. produce a blank line. The only difference is it would print a trailing word, whereas the OP's code doesn't print the last word if not followed by a a space.